# Android Gridview OnScrollListener ScrollUp and ScrollDown event

Tags: android, gridview

I have gridview and I need to do two things:

When I scroll down, I want to find the last visible position e.g `int index = GridView.getLastVisiblePosition();`

When I scroll up, I want to find the first visible position e.g `int index = GridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();`

I know I can use the following code, but I'm not sure how and where to write a code for ScrollUp and ScrollDown. Please help me. I am new to Android.

```
private OnScrollListener onAnswersScrolled = new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Create global variable `myLastVisiblePos` in your activity, and save for each FirstVisiblePosition, when onScroll event check current FirstVisiblePosition with your saved FirstVisiblePosition if greate than your last saved FirstVisiblePosition then scrollUp if small then scrollDown:

```
int myLastVisiblePos;// global variable of activity

//save first value when you create GridView
GridView gridView = (GridView) gv.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
myLastVisiblePos = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

gridView.setOnScrollListener( new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int currentFirstVisPos = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            if(currentFirstVisPos > myLastVisiblePos) {
                //scroll down
            }
            if(currentFirstVisPos < myLastVisiblePos) {
                //scroll up
            }
            myLastVisiblePos = currentFirstVisPos;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely try this option. On my screen if I scroll little bit I can see both first and last visible position at the same time. I am thinking I might have to change the

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely try this option. On my screen if I scroll little bit up or down I can see both first and last visible position at the same time. If I scroll down and leave it in the miiddle I want to display lastvisible position on the screen and similar way if I scroll up I want to display firstvisible position on the screen. I am thinking I might have to change the myLastVisiblePos = GridView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); to myLastVisiblePos = GridView.getLastVisiblePosition(); otherwise I am comparing 1=1 in first if statement. Please help.

Comment: Shri Ksai I honestly do not understand your question, you can add a screenshot to understand what you want send my email

Comment: Superb Man.. Awesome answer. +1

Comment: it detect scroll up or down after one item or first row goes up... can not detect urgent scroll

Answer (score 2):

Try this Code may be helpful to you..

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) gv.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
gridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("GridView","firstVisibleItem"+firstVisibleItem+"\nLastVisibleItem"+totalItemCount);
            }
        }
    });
```