# Android Gridview OnScrollListener ScrollUp and ScrollDown event (in Fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, floating-action-button

I already read this question : [Android Gridview OnScrollListener ScrollUp and ScrollDown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370099/android-gridview-onscrolllistener-scrollup-and-scrolldown-event)

I tried using its logic to get the current and last item position, but since I am having my gridview under fragments. Therefore, I am always getting value of current item for the next available fragment.

I want to detect the scroll up event and hide some Floating Action Buttons on my Activity.

Can someone please suggest what can be done to achieve my above mentioned purpose. Any modifications to the existing logic from the attached question OR any new way to find scroll up and down events are welcomed.

Comment: Check google io app code in BaseActivity there is code where they hide the toolbar on scroll of listview. You can use the same

Comment: @Raghunandan Can u provide some source link or code please?

Comment: https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java. Look @ onActionBarShowOrHide. The actionbar animates and goes off screen when you scroll list and when you scroll up you see the actionbar again. The same concept can be applied for fab.

Comment: @Raghunandan But I dont want to refresh my fragment using SwipeRefreshLayout. My fragments are already loaded; just want to know when is the scroll up or down event triggered.

Comment: pls look at the code once again. Pick those that are relevant. It will work. You can forget the part that has swipe refresh

Comment: Sorry :( but its not relevant to me. Could you have some other approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101149/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-ali-waris).